# Make Random Numbers Generator with average value

Tags: c++, random, numbers

I need to make random numbers generator without built-in function and with an average value of not more than 0.5.
It must generate 10000 numbers and preferably they should not be repeated.
For example code of PRNG below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

unsigned int Rand()
{
    static unsigned int seed = 5323;
    seed = 8253729 * seed + 2396403;
    return seed  % 32768;
}

int main()
{
    for (int count=1; count <= 10000; ++count)
{
        cout << Rand() << "\t";
        if (count % 10 == 0)
        cout << "\n";
}

    return 0;
}
```

As a result I have 10000 numbers, and if I try to calculate average value of 10 numbers from the first line I won't receive 0.5. For example in first line we receive:

```
31222,24489,32444,25391,6402,11317,10440,6843,3598,3777
```

The average value is: 15592.3.
What can I do with it to decrease this value?

Comment: As is this is almost impossible.  You generate numbers in the range of [0, 23767]  and the average of that should be ~11883.  To get `.5` you either need to narrow your range, add negative numbers, or use a built in solution that can guarantee this.

Comment: In addition to what @NathanOliver said - it seems obvious that the goal is to have a function which generates random floating point numbers between 0.0 and 1.0. A crude way to simulate this given your code is to cast the result to a float and divide it by your maximum value. There will only be 32767 possible values, but their average will be around 0.5.

Comment: You need to provide some more information about what exactly you intend to generate as random numbers. Do you need uniformly distributed Real numbers in between 0 and 1, a'la [0,1), where the average will be [very nearly] exactly 0.5? Or do you need normally distributed numbers with an average of 0.5?

Comment: _"...10,000 numbers and preferably they __should not be repeated__..."_: fill an array with 0 .. 10,000.  Shuffle the array. Divide each element by 10,000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Don't try to roll your own PRNG

If you get a degree in cryptography, or otherwise end up specializing in PRNG development, you will learn the necessary techniques as part of your education or training. Trying to do that outside that context is just going to give you bad results.

## Use the `<random>` Library

C++ has library features that are intended to make this kind of problem as painless as possible to solve.

```
#include<random>
#include<iostream>

float get_random_value() {
    static std::default_random_engine engine{std::random_device()()};
    static std::uniform_real_distribution<float> distribution{0, 1};
    
    return distribution(engine);
}

int main() {
    for (int count=1; count <= 10000; ++count) {
        std::cout << get_random_value() << "\t";
        if (count % 10 == 0)
            std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

The components of this code look like this:

- `std::default_random_engine` is an alias for whichever PRNG your library implementation feels is ideal for default use. This usually defaults to `std::mt19937`, which is a type of PRNG called the "Mersenne Twister". The [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) reference contains lots of other engines you could instead consider.
- `std::random_device` is a library feature for requesting "entropy" from the operating system. All you need to worry about is that this is constructed once, called to generate a "seed", and then discarded and not used again. If you don't use this or if you hard code the value returned by this call, the engine will always produce the same values in the same order every time your program is run.
- `std::uniform_real_distribution` is a distribution. Using the parameters specified for this distribution, you can directly specify the range of the distribution. We used `0` and `1` so the distribution will return evenly distributed numbers between 0 and 1. There are other distributions available, which you can find described in the reference.
- Getting a value is as easy as invoking the call operator on the distribution object, using the engine as its sole parameter.

This code will reliably generate numbers in the range [0, 1), and it does so in an idiomatic, expressive manner. If you need uniform values in a different range, it's easy to adjust this code to handle it. If you need non-uniform values (like for a normal distribution), there are other distributions (like [`std::normal_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution)) that properly handle that situation.

Answer (score 0):

`Rand() / 32767.0` will have a mean value of 0.5.

What you need is knowledge around maths, statistics. Search for expectation, uniform distribution.